# Orcad Capture CIS, How to change transistor area?

Tags: pspice, orcad

If using the QbreakN and QbreakP, how could I change the relative emitter areas of each individual transistor.

I need to match the parameters like in the figure below:
[image]

Comment: Does the netlister permit an integer scale factor to be used on each transistor symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have placed your breakout model, you right click on it -> "Edit PSice Model". In this window where you also change your model parameters, change the model name to something else, like QbreakN1. When you save it, your model will refer to QbreakN1, but your new models you add to the schematic will still refer to the original model.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate that, however I'm still not sure how i would go about changing the emitter area, as i haven't been able to find any documentation explaining this. I guess for example: Area = 1um^2 might work, but im not sure if the program will recognize "area" and what im referring to.

Comment: @Kluski: Im not sure if emitter area is a variable design parameter like Width and length in a FET, isn't it normally "Is" which you vary?

Comment: And "Is" being dependent on the emitter area, or vice versa.

Comment: Actually, my original post is about a fully BJT design, but i think the procedure you have here for the Mbreaks is the same as it would be for Qbreaks. But yeah, you're right about the Is concerning the FETs.

Comment: Either way, you can disregard the question as I've finished the project via a different route.

Comment: @Kluski: Sure, but the way models works is the same, being a fet, bjt or diode. Doing a quick google search for "pspice bjt model parameters" doesn't  show me any parameters to specify the emitter area, thus i concluded this is not a normal design parameter.